# Why does a program crashing but being normal when debugging (using code blocks)

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am solving Contest Scoreboard (UVA(10258), PC(110207)), and wrote a C++ code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

//100 contestants, 9 problems.
//data need to store for each contestant: num of problem solved, time consumed.
//array of contestants' data should be sorted by those two values. <- vector of pairs
//problem solved <- set
//time consumed <- check for contestant and L for each line and add them up.

std::vector< std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int> > > contestants;

std::vector<std::set<int>> problem_solved; //store contestants' solved problems

void add_entry(std::string line)
{
    int begin = 0;
    int end = line.find(" ", begin);
    int contestant = std::atoi(line.substr(0, end - begin).c_str());
    begin = end + 1;
    end = line.find(" ", begin);
    int problem = atoi(line.substr(begin, end - begin).c_str());
    begin = end + 1;
    end = line.find(" ", begin);
    int time = atoi(line.substr(begin, end - begin).c_str());
    char status = line.back();

    switch (status)
    {
    case 'C':
        {
            if (!problem_solved[contestant].count(problem))
            {
                problem_solved[contestant].insert(problem);
            }
            break;
        }
    case 'I':
        time = 20;
        break;
    default:
        time = 0;
        break;
    }

    contestants[contestant].first = contestant;
    contestants[contestant].second.second += time;
}

bool comp(std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>> a, std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>> b)
{
    if (a.second.first == b.second.first)
    {
        return (a.second.second <= b.second.second);
    }
    else
    {
        return (a.second.first > b.second.first);
    }
}

void calc_results()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        contestants[i].second.first = problem_solved[i].size();
    }

    std::sort(contestants.begin(), contestants.end(), comp);
}

int main()
{
    //initialize it so that contestants with no records can be ruled out
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        contestants.push_back(std::make_pair(0, std::make_pair(0, 0)));
    }

    //initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        problem_solved.push_back(std::set<int>{});
    }

    std::string line_1;
    int num_case;
    std::getline(std::cin, line_1);
    //get number of cases
    num_case = atoi(line_1.c_str());
    //get one blank line
    std::string blank;
    std::getline(std::cin, blank);
    //get num_case 's cases.
    int i = 0;
    std::string line_2;
    while (i < num_case)
    {
        //get unknown number of entries
        std::getline(std::cin, line_2);
        //move to next case
        if (line_2.empty())
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            //handle one line of entry
            add_entry(line_2);
        }
    }

    //calculate final results
    calc_results();

    //print results
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
        if (contestants[i].second.first == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << contestants[i].first << " " << contestants[i].second.first << " " << contestants[i].second.second << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run debug, it behaves normally:

```
1 2 66
3 1 11
```

But when I run the executable directly, the output is like:

```
some large integers some large integers some large integers
1 2 66
3 1 11
```

Then the program crashed, showing "Process returned -1073741819".

I suspect that it is some kind of memory leak, but can't understand what happened. Could anyone give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: Your comparison function is not a strict weak ordering, which leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Aside: `std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>` is an unwieldy type. Can you use `struct contestant { int id; int solved_count; int time_used; };`?

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, I am a newcomer and never thought about it.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you, it was a stupid mistake.